# Why ceil function of matlab and java are different?

Tags: java, matlab

I am using ceil function in JAVA. I would like to compare that function with MATLAB. However, it returns different value when I use it in MATLAB. For example, I have H=7, I use that code in JAVA

```
int H=7;
double Hp= Math.ceil(H/2);
```

It returns 3. 
However, I use that function in MATLAB

```
Hp= ceil(H/2);
```

It returns 4. What is true in here? How to achieve the result similar ceil function in JAVA? Thank you in advance

Comment: Is `H/2` perhaps giving 3 in Java and 3.5 in Matlab? Try `H/2.0`

Comment: Declaring `H = 7` in MATLAB automatically promotes the type of the number to `double`.  In fact, unless you specifically change the data type of the number, all numbers are created as `double`.  Therefore, doing `ceil(H/2)` will produce `4.0`, as `H/2 = 3.5`.

Comment: @rayryeng: Thank you. How to achieve the result looks like JAVA result (3) . Is it ceil(H/2)-1?

Comment: @user8430 - You can do that... or you could use `floor`? `double Hp = Math.floor(H / 2.0);`?  However, be careful when subtracting by 1 when `H` is negative if you decide to use that definition with `ceil`.

Comment: @rayryeng: No, I am considering MATLAB function in here. I think my ceil expression is similar floor function in MATLAB, Is it right?

Comment: @user8430 - If you're expecting `3` as the output, then the answer is yes.

Comment: @user8430 `ceil` is round up, `floor` is round down. They're opposites.

Comment: @user8430 - I still don't quite understand why you are using `ceil` in conjunction with an integer.  Performing `H/2` when `H` is an integer will truncate the floating point results and so you get 3.  Doing `ceil` on this would be superfluous.  Instead of trying to convince us that 3 is the expected result, why don't you tell us what this code will ultimately be used for?  It'll give us better insight and it'll probably stop us from considering what you're doing to be total voodoo.

Comment: This is my work "Given H be the integer, H' = ceil(H/2)". So I would like to find H' from H. I choose H=7 and perform ceil function. I used both language MATLAB and JAVA to find the H'. From that equation, JAVA give a true result. However, matlab returns a different result. As us discuss, I think that if we want to achieve the result looks like that equation, we have to use floor function in MATLAB

Comment: From a mathematical point, if your goal is to calculate `H' = ceil(H/2)`, then Matlab gives you the *correct* result and Java gives you the *wrong* result. `7/2=3.5` and `ceil(3.5)` is per definition 4.

Comment: The difference is in the /, not in the ceil.

Answer (score 4):

To answer "How to achieve the result similar ceil function in JAVA?", you can use [`idivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/idivide.html) with an integer cast on one of the arguments:

```
H  = 7;
Hp = idivide(H,int8(2));
```

This will perform the division and round the fractional part toward 0 by default.  The `ceil` function is unnecessary since integer division generates integers.  You can wrap this in a `ceil` but nothing will happen.

---

Note: The use of `idivide` is required since MATLAB's implementation of integer arithmetic (quite counter-intuitively in my experience) actually rounds the fractional portion of an integer division to the nearest integer (at least on R2014b):

```
Hp = int8(7) /int8(2) ; % 3.5 float => 4 integer
Hp = int8(34)/int8(10); % 3.4 float => 3 integer
```

I suspect this has to do with some type casting by the `rdivide` function.

Answer (score 2):

You are performing integer math. You wanted something like

```
int H = 7;
double Hp = Math.ceil(H / 2.0);
System.out.println(Hp);
```

Output is

```
4.0
```

If you expect `3` you would need something like

```
int H = 7;
int Hp = (int) Math.floor(H / 2.0);
System.out.println(Hp);
```

Output is

```
3
```

Comment: How to achieve result 3 ? Because my question is How to achieve the result similar ceil function in JAVA?

Comment: @user8430 - Why do you want 3? That is contrary to the definition of `ceil`.

Comment: @user8430 Your question was *which is correct*, and the answer is 4 (for `ceil`)... if you expect 3 you need to use `floor`.

Comment: Actually, 3 is my expected result. I am using a function in java looks like above function. And now, I want to convert it to matlab.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: The my JAVA code is correct. I want to convert my JAVA code to MATLAB code. It is my expected work

Comment: Then you have to force the division to an integer before passing it to ceil, so it'd be more or less ceil(floor(h / 2)).